# iPhoneXでナビゲーションバーとステータスバーの表示／非表示を別々に制御する方法

Tags: ios, navigationbar, iphone-x

一つのiOSアプリケーションで`NavigationBar`と`StatusBar`の表示／非表示を画面によって制御したいと思っています．

**iPhone6**, **iPhone7** and **iPhone8**では，意図通りに表示できています．
最初の画面ではステータスバーもナビゲーションバーも表示されず，
次の画面ではステータスバーは非表示のままで，ナビゲーションバーは表示されます．

[image]

しかし**iPhoneX**では，`NavigationBar`を表示すると`StatusBar`も一緒に表示されてしまいます．

`ViewController`での`prefersStatusBarHidden`はYESに設定しています.

また`NavigationBar`の高さも`StatusBar`の分が加わったような高さになってしまいます．

[image]

解決方法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたいと思います．

よろしくお願いします．

コードは以下のような感じです．

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor;

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}                                 }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)touchUpButton:(UIButton *)button
                                  {
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"SecondView";

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

本家（英語版）のほうのStackOverFlowでも質問をしていたのですが，**iPhoneXの挙動**ということで，ナビゲーションバーを表示して，ステータスバーを表示しない．ということは出来ないそうです．

- On iPhoneX, Control Show / Hide NavigationBar and StatusBar separately
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207378/on-iphonex-control-show-hide-navigationbar-and-statusbar-separately

また認識はしていましたが，AppleのUIガイドラインでもiPhoneXではステータスバーを表示するのが推奨とのことです．

Comment: [human interface guidelinesのステータスバーについて](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/status-bars/)でステータスバーを一時的にではなく恒久的に隠すのはよろしくない旨が書いてますね。

Comment: @Myaku [https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/)ですね．「If your app currently hides the status bar, reconsider that decision for iPhone X. （中略）The status bar also displays information people find useful. It should only be hidden in exchange for added value.」と記載がありますね．